# Comment option disappears after deleting comment

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web, deleted-comments

On a mobile device if I add a comment to a post and then delete the comment, the option to add a comment again (to the same post) is hidden.

The comment link appears again after the page is refreshed.

Issue also present on super user.

Not sure if this is by design  but seems like a bug.

Chrome browser, android, P10 lite

Screen shot after I delete a comment (no option to comment)

[image]

Here's some repro steps with screen shots as requested:

**Adding comment with panel initially visible:**

[image]

**Saved comment with links / panel visible:**

[image]

**After clicking delete link comment panel collapses:**

[image]

This only happens when there is a single comment on the post and deleting that comment leaves the post with 0 comments. Reproduced on SO and Meta-SO, so *safe-ish* to say it's across the network.

The panel comes back when you refresh page.

Android mobile chrome browser viewing mobile website.

Comment: I'm sure this is an old one, but can't find a dupe just yet.

Comment: When you say mobile, do you mean the mobile *theme*? Or are you viewing the full site on a mobile device? ...or are you using the mobile *app*?

Comment: On a mobile phone @shog9

Comment: Mind posting a screenshot?

Comment: Done @Shog9....

Comment: Heh... A screenshot of the missing comment link if you can (I've been trying to reproduce this without luck)

Comment: It doesn't happen here.... Only in SO and Su (that I tried) @Shog9... I also have to go so I hope you can replicate

Comment: @shog9 have posted screenshots if you're interested... Just realised his screen shot shows the issue too...

Comment: @dave it does happen here too, but only when there is a single comment being deleted, leaving you with 0 comments. probably +/- 1 error somewhere.