# Where did comment links and timestamps go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments, user-interface

Today, on refreshing a tab with a Stack Overflow question open, the dates of the comments disappeared - I mean the links to the comments:

[image]

became:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: They still seem to be there for me

Comment: That's good - but still I haven't updated my browser or anything - on firefox esr 52.6.0 (64-bit)

Comment: I noticed it just now - I guess as I spent a lot of time in there I would have noticed immediately

Comment: My point was it doesn't appear to be a change that has actually occurred unless you're part of an A/B test that removes them.

Comment: I don't remember opting in for such a test - is there a such a proposed change ? I hope not

Comment: When I refresh the page they momentarily appear and then disappear - strange thing is I did not change anything on my side - disabling uBlock origin does not help

Comment: Loaded my lightweight firefox - still no joy

Comment: cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/date-time-on-comments but that one is marked as status-norepro.

Comment: Can you try with Chrome? Or a more recent version of FF?

Comment: I could try with chrome - re: other firefox version - I hadn't upadated esr in while - so something else changed

Comment: Hmm - posting this from chrome - works fine. So some kind of bug on FF that came to light with some recent change in SO ?

Comment: Yes, this site changes now that it finally can use all CSS3 goodies. CSS and html structure is getting re-done, so better keep a recent browser handy.

Comment: Probably related: ["*work is undergoing to revamp some layout stuff including comments*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362771/2821954)

Comment: Please make sure the time/date stamps are restored to comments after the revamp is complete -- there is no way to determine how stale the question and discussion is without them. (I too have current FF 52.6esr and the time/date stamps just disappeared within the last hour or two)

Comment: Also note the upvote and vote total on comments have also disappeared. I can upvote a comment and the hover windows says I have upvoted it, but the number of upvotes (including mine) are not displayed any longer.

Comment: I also have been experiencing all of the issues described here. Some portions of it I noticed yesterday. I can confirm that I only experience it on Firefox 52ESR (both 52.5.3 and 52.6.0). On FF52ESR it happens with all userscripts turned off and in multiple profiles. I do not experience the issue on Chrome or Firefox 58.0.1. Interestingly, if I open the Firefox DevTools to the Inspector (DevTools tab) the comment timestamp/link magically reappears along with the comment vote count, but may then disappear again. Opening the Console (DevTools tab) does not result in a change in visibility.

Comment: Everything's fine on Chrome. Suggest you state your browser name, version, subversion. Also versions of any plugins that might be affecting things; perhaps one of your plugins auto-updated itself? Try restarting your browser with plugins disabled to confirm.

Comment: No repro on Safari 11, macOS 10.13.3.

Comment: related perhaps: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362732/comment-option-disappears-after-deleting-comment/362736#362736

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying my answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306461/date-time-on-comments/306503#306503):

> This is a really bad browser bug. And while we don't officially support FF 52, it seems used widely enough (because it's ESR) that this issue is probably worth working around.
>
> Basically, the layout engine decides that the timestamp has a width of zero pixels, and we have to force the browser to re-calculate the layout.
>
> This workaround is deployed here on Meta and will be on the rest of the network in a few minutes.)

Comment: Reported fixed - thanks!

Comment: I can see the timestamps here (FF52.6esr) -- so there is hope `:)`